# How in android in ExpandableListView set bounds for indicator?

Tags: android

How in android in ExpandableListView set bounds for indicator ?
In java code I am doing like this, but how to solve this on xml level, bounds.

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.indicator);
list.setIndicatorBounds(100, 100);
list.setGroupIndicator(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code would look in XML like this:

```
<ExpandableListView

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/indicator"
android:indicatorLeft="100dip"
android:indicatorRight="100dip" />
```